# Trying to schedule a function using schedule library. Getting "Invalid Time Format" error

Tags: python, time, schedule

**I'm trying to schedule a "job" at a time picked by user input. When trying to input the time I get a "Invalid Time format" error.
I'm a beginner and am thinking it has to do with how to work with time in python. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.**

import schedule

h = what_hour()

m = what_min()

schedule.every().day.at("h:m").do(single_alarm_sound)

Comment: Nowhere near enough code to figure out what you're doing.  But, what happens if you change to: `schedule.every().day.at(f"{h}:{m}").do(single_alarm_sound)`?

Comment: This worked and I thank you. Does the f always go right before the quotation marks? I'll review string formatting thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
schedule.every().day.at(f"{h}:{m}").do(single_alarm_sound)
```

More on f-string formatting here: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

It's a very nice feature, where you can inject variables, etc right into the string.